# Default menus not visible in backend , also frontend not loading properly

Tags: magento

I disabled some modules in backend in `System> configuration>Advanced >Advanced`

than i log out and login and than some default magento menus are not visible.

also frontend looking like [this site](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/)

[image]

Comment: May i know which module you have disabled ? I think you have disabled core module so menu gone

Comment: @SunnyRathod its really strange for me, i disbaled extension only. i dont want to inform here as extension reputation may go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i run this query : `SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE '%advanced/modules_disable_output/%' ORDER BY path ASC` and checked in database and enabled all modules by changing value to 1. finally it was problem with some custom module.